# Recording video from camera Java Android

Tags: java, android

I require the abilty to record MP4 video at High (720 x 480) or Low (360 x 240) on the devices running Android 2.2 (or above) or Android 3.0 and above.Currently I can record on all devices but the resolution varries on each device and I can not figure out how to force each device to record at the resolutions stated above. Give me an example of code please.

Comment: You probably cannot. Not all devices are equal

Comment: If I know that my device support this video size how I can set size from my task?

Answer (score 0):

Each device has own list of supported video sizes. You need to get this list with [getSupportedVideoSizes](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedVideoSizes%28%29) method and pick one that is close to your requirements.

Here is a method which is able to return list of supported sizes (but it should be called before any other Camera or MediaRecorder objects are initialized):

```
List<Camera.Size> getSupporteVideoSizes() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
        Camera.Parameters params = camera.getParameters();
        return params.getSupportedVideoSizes();
    }
    finally {
        if (camera != null) 
            camera.release();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I don't find working examples for my task. Did you create anything with videocamera?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a video from camera, but I don't need video recording so I have no complete code sample for sharing.